# Proof on irrationality, proof on inequality with lub/glb

Tags: real-analysis

Are my proofs elaborate, yet concise? Is there something missing, or am I adding too much?

> Let $E$ be a nonempty subset of an ordered set; suppose $\alpha$ is a lower bound of $E$ and $\beta$ an upper bound of $E$. Prove $\alpha \leq \beta$

Since $\alpha$ is a lower bound of $E$, then $$\forall e\in E \exists \alpha \in L : \alpha \leq e$$ Then every $e$ is an upper bound for $L$, and so $L$ is bounded above. Call the least upper bound of $L$ $\sup L = e_{0}$; we end up with the inequality $\alpha \leq e_{0} \leq \beta$. QED.

> Prove $\sqrt{15}$ is irrational.

Suppose instead that $\sqrt{15}$ is rational. Then $$\exists p, q \in \Bbb Z : {\frac{p^2}{q^2}} = 15 \rightarrow p^2 = 15q^2.$$

This implies $15 | p^2$ and thus $15 | p$ (since there is no common factor between $q$ and $p$). But the only factors of $15$ are $3$ and $5$, and $p^2$ cannot be compromised of two factors. RAA.

Comment: $\exists \alpha$ is not right. We are **told** that $\alpha$ is a lower bound. So immediately $\alpha\le e$ for any $e\in E$. Then later there is some stuff about a least upper bound. This is quite wrong, nothing about our set says there is a least upper bound. There very well might not be one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't define $L$, so the rest of that proof is quite confusing. A far more direct approach would be to say something like:

Since $E$ is non-empty, choose $e \in E$. Since $\alpha$ is a lower bound for $E$, we have $\alpha\le e$; likewise, $e \le \beta$. Hence, $\alpha \le \beta$.

For the second proof, it's mistaken. The fact that $15 | p$ does not follow from the fact that $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime; it follows from the fact that $15 | p^2$, and can be justified by the fact that $15 = 3 \cdot 5$ is a product of two *distinct* primes. Furthermore, $p$ wasn't assumed to prime and there's absolutely no reason to assume that $p^2$ cannot have two (distinct, non-trivial) factors.

Hence, a rather different argument needs to be made.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are integers $a$ and $b$ such that $\frac{a}{b}=\sqrt{15}$. We may assume that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.

Then $a^2=15b^2$. Since the prime $3$ divides $a^2$, it follows that $3$ divides $a$. So $a=3c$ for some $c$.

Thus $9c^2=15b^2$, and therefore $3c^2=5b^2$. Since $3$ and $5$ are relatively prime, it follows that $3$ divides $b^2$, and therefore $3$ divides $b$. This contradicts the fact that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.

Comment: Great answer, it is more clear than what I wrote

Comment: Try to divide your arguments into small steps for which the logic is clear. After a while, in more advanced work, you can take larger steps.